# Getting source of AdjustmentListener event in AWT

Tags: java, events, awt, listener

I have different AdjustmentListeners like:

```
a.addAdjustmentListener(this);
b.addAdjustmentListener(this);
c.addAdjustmentListener(this);
```

I have a method that implements adjustmentValueChanged:

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){

}
```

I would like to perform different actions based on which one of a, b, c was called. Let's say,

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
    String a = //the method I am looking for        
        if(a == "a") {
            // do something
        } else if(a == "b"){
            // do something else
        } else if(a == "c"){
            // do something else
        }
}
```

I know for ActionEvent, there is getActionCommand().toString(). Is there something like that for AdjustmentEvent?

Or how do I deal with which Event occured?

To be more explicit a,b,c are JScrollbars.

Comment: AdjustmentEvent extends AWTEvent and AWTEvent extends EventObject and EventObject has setSource() and getSource() methods. Basically you should be able to call e.getSource() on your AdjustmentEvent object e. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a name for a, b, c:

```
JScrollbar a = ...;
a.setName("a");
```

and in the listener method evaluate the name to find out which scrollbar caused the event:

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
    String name = ((JScrollbar)e.getAdjustable()).getName();
    if ("a".equals(name)) {
            // do a something
    } else if ...
```

Another solution could be to compare the adjustable with references to a, b, c if they are stored in fields accessible by the listener method:

```
JScrollbar a, b, c; // class fields in the listener or an outer class

public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
    if (a == e.getAdjustable()) {
            // do a something
    } else if ...
```

Answer (score 1):

AdjustmentEvent extends AWTEvent which in turn extends java.util.EventObject having methods getSource() which returns a reference to the element that caused the event and setSource() allowing you to set source for an event.

You could basically try the following to differentiate between the source of the event:

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == a) {
            // do something
    } else if(e.getSource() == b){
            // do something else
    } else if(e.getSource() == c){
            // do something else
   }
}
```

If necessary, you could event cast the object

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
      JScrollbar temp = (JScrollbar) e.getSource();
        if(temp == a) {
                // do something
        } else if(temp == b){
                // do something else
        } else if(temp == c){
                // do something else
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't scale - what if you have some more scroll bars?  Suddenly you're going to have huge if-then or switch statements.

A cleaner (and more OO, if that's important to you) is to use a specific listener per scrollbar.

If you need access to inner values of your parent class (`this` in your example), you can use anonymous classes.  With Java 8's lambas, the resulting code is far cleaner.

```
public class Example {

    // ...

    private void initUI() {
        // ...

        a.addAdjustmentListener(e -> foo());
        b.addAdjustmentListener(e -> bar());
        // or do something directly within the lambda...
        c.addAdjustmentListener(e -> System.out.println("c changed"));
    }

    private void foo(final JScrollBar scrollBar) {
        // do something based on the provided scroll bar
    }

    private void bar(final JScrollBar scrollBar) {
        // do something based on the provided scroll bar
    }
}
```